# Vue Routing - prevent re-rendering the page?

Tags: vue.js

I have `News.vue` and `News-View.vue`. When I route to `news/1`, it opens the `News-View.vue` page. The problem is that I have many search filters (category, date, etc.) and infinite scroll in `News.vue`. This means, that when the user gets back from `News-View.vue`, everything re-renders and refreshes, and the user's preferences are cleared. Is there a way to not re-render the `News.vue` page?

**News.Vue:**

```
beforeMount: async function () {
  this.$axios.post('http://localhost/?action=news', this.filters).then((response) => {
    this.results = this.results.concat(response)
  })
}
```

P.S. I'm currently using `State Management` for saving the loaded results and saved scroll position and it works, but again, I was wondering is there a way to just not re-render a page, but save the current state or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the `keep-alive` tag:

```
<keep-alive>
  <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

https://router.vuejs.org/api/

However, you'll need to tweak it a little bit because I'm not sure you would want that behavior for your entire app?

Comment: I could definitely use it on my entire app. It's actually a mobile app, so I think it would be better if it's that way. But does it effect the performance?

Comment: Well, I think that yes it affects performances in a positive way, but you need to be careful in for components where you would have into the created hook a function that fetches a resource from the the route params. This function will not run again because of the keep alive even if you change route. So you would need to add a watcher or something like this.

Comment: Actually I was worrying that it may affect it in a negative way (memory usage, etc). Thank you very much, I'll do it now! :-)

Comment: Ho well, actually you may be right for the memory usage effect. This will depend on the size of the data you store into your components, or the number of components you have in your app. All of this is really specific to your app

Comment: I don't think it would be a problem, it's very simple and lightweight app. Thanks for your help! I can't wait to start it :-))