# iview How to keep vue page status in a vue page which have a iframe inside in it between tab switch

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, iview

I have two pages (tabA and tabB) using vue and vue-router,iview,user can switch tabs between tabA and tabB,tabA is a normal vue page,tabB is a vue page which includes iframe inside in tabB,when I switch to tabA and then click to back to tabB,however,tabB's iframe inside was refreshed,How can i keep tabB's iframe status and don't refresh between tab switchs,I tried ,however,It is useless, So what should I do to keep tabB's iframe status between tab switchs?
My pages like this:

tabA

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Card>
      something...  
    </Card>
  </div>
</template>
```

tabB

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Card>
      <div >
      <iframe  src="xxx.com">
  something
      </iframe>
        </div>
    </Card>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Each time when you go back to tab B, Vue will re-render this component, so there should be something what will stop re-render. `keep-alive` tag could help you, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624894/vue-routing-prevent-re-rendering-the-page

Comment: thanks for share,I will check it,i searched on google find a way to solve it,It use v-show to hide iframe content,https://programmer.help/blogs/keep-alive-no-refresh-for-iframe-in-vue.html